# TextField widgets lose focus (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, textfield

I am creating an app with Flutter `TextField` widgets:

```dart
class CategoryData {
  int? id;
  String name;
  String description;

  CategoryData({this.id, required this.name, required this.description});
}

class CategoriesEdit extends StatefulWidget {
  Database? db;
  CategoryData? category;

  CategoriesEdit({super.key, required this.db, required this.category});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => CategoriesEditState();
}

class CategoriesEditState extends State<CategoriesEdit> {
  CategoryData? category;

  void saveState(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (category == null) {
      setState(() {
        category = widget.category ?? CategoryData(name: "", description: "");
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: InkWell(
              child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_left),
              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
          title: const Text("Edit Category"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Column(key: const Key('name'), children: [
            const Text("Category name:*"),
            TextField(
                controller: TextEditingController(text: category!.name),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    category!.name = value;
                  });
                })
          ]),
          Column(key: const Key('description'), children: [
            const Text("Description:"),
            TextField(
                controller: TextEditingController(text: category!.description),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    category!.description = value;
                  });
                })
          ]),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => saveState(context), // passing false
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
            OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
              // passing false
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
          ]),
        ]));
  }
}
```

But after I type a character in one of these two widgets, the cursor moves before the first character and the Android keyboard widget disappears. Why? And how to fix that bug?

I tried adding widget keys, but as you see it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

**You do not have to do**

**controller: TextEditingController(text: category!.name)**

because the controller's text automatically changes once you connect it to TextField.

The reason is once you set some text to the controller, it re-applies the text thus moving the cursor to the front.

I have solved this for you :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CategoryData {
  int? id;
  String name;
  String description;

  CategoryData({this.id, required this.name, required this.description});
}

class CategoriesEdit extends StatefulWidget {
  CategoryData? category;

  CategoriesEdit({required this.category});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => CategoriesEditState();
}

class CategoriesEditState extends State<CategoriesEdit> {
  CategoryData? category;
  // Database? db;
  TextEditingController nametextController =  TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descriptionTextController = TextEditingController();
  void saveState(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (category == null) {
      setState(() {
        category = widget.category ?? CategoryData(name: "", description: "");
      });


    }
    nametextController.text = category!.name??"";
    descriptionTextController.text = category!.description??"";



    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: InkWell(
              child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_left),
              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
          title: const Text("Edit Category"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Column(key: const Key('name'), children: [
            const Text("Category name:*"),
            TextField(
                controller: nametextController,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    category!.name = value;
                  });
                })
          ]),
          Column(key: const Key('description'), children: [
            const Text("Description:"),
            TextField(
                controller: descriptionTextController,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    category!.description = value;
                  });
                })
          ]),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => saveState(context), // passing false
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
            OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
              // passing false
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
          ]),
        ]));
  }
}
```

I have tested this code and it is working fine, let me know if you have any doubt. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of things going wrong here, not only the stuff mentioned in the other answer.

1. Move the setState in the builder into initState:

   ```
   if (category == null) {
     setState(() {
       category = widget.category ?? CategoryData(name: "", description: "");
     });
   }
   ```
2. Don't use `setState` in the `onChanged` callback. Change:

   ```
   onChanged: (value) {
     setState(() {
       category!.description = value;
     });
   }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   onChanged: (value) {
     category!.description = value;
   }
   ```
3. Store the `TextEditingController`s, because you have to dispose them once we dispose the state.
4. If you are already using `TextEditingController`s, then you don't need the `onChanged` callback. Just take text from the controller like explained in the other answer.